# Incoming call number not displayed

Tags: android

I tried to check if my phone is showing up the incoming number after a call using a toast but its not working, its showing empty value in the number (I used my own phone to test application not an emulator).
Here is the code:

```
package com.practise.calling;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView textView1;
Boolean prevState=false;    

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    PhoneStateListener callStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Phone Is Riging",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Phone is Currently in A call", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                prevState = true;
            }

            if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "phone is neither ringing nor in a call"+incomingNumber,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.i("NUMBER",incomingNumber);
                if(prevState==true){
                Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                in.putExtra("NUMBER",incomingNumber);
                startActivity(in);
                }
                prevState=false;

            }
        }
    };
    telephonyManager.listen(callStateListener,
            PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the call state is "ringing" then you can get the phone number. Otherwise it can't get the incoming number.

Code:

```
PhoneStateListener.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
    String number = incomingNumber;
```

Answer (score 1):

somehow do you forget to add incomingNumber in your CALL_STATE_RINGING and CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK ?

change this 2 lines

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Phone Is Riging"+incomingNumber,
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
    "Phone is Currently in A call"+incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
    .show();
```

Comment: Sorry I didnt get you, the Toast is working fine but number is not getting displayed.

Comment: You didn't add the incomingNumber variable to the Toast message, and thus it's not shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this in BroadcastReceiver it will work....

```
    String incomingNumber;
        if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
incomingNumber=intent.getStringExtra("incoming_number");
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Phone Is Ringing "+incomingNumber,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else if (state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {

                Toast.makeText(context, "Call is Idle "+incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            } else if (state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Offhook State "+incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
```

Comment: Abhi I found out the problem in my code... To get the phone number we should catch the value in ringing or off hook state but not in idle state.....